# Segmentation Fault (Core dumped) - where is the error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I have a basic C program that I have to do for a Personal Software Processes assignment. I'm fairly new to C so I honestly can't see where I've gone wrong. Please read through and let me know what I'm doing that's causing it to crash?

I've got to read in a file, and store the values as an array. It comes up with no compiling errors, just a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define array_limit   100

int main (void)

{  
  FILE *ifp;
  char *mode = "r";
  ifp = fopen("samplepopulation.txt", mode);  


  if (ifp==NULL)
  {
    printf("cannot read file \n");
  }  
  else
  {   
    int i;
    float sample; 

    float values[array_limit];
    i = 0;

    do
    {
       fscanf(ifp, "%f", &sample);
       if (!feof(ifp))
       {
          values[i] = sample;
          printf("%f \n", values[i]);
          i++;
            if (i>array_limit)
            {
               printf("File larger than allowed/n");
               break;
            }
       }

       else
       {
          printf("read complete");
       }

    } while (ifp!= EOF);     
  }

  fclose(ifp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right NOW is the time to learn how to use a debugger:)

Comment: You have tagged this post with the C tag, but you are not declaring the variables at the beginning of your code. Take care of this kind of things...

Comment: What is `ifp != EOF` doing? ifp is a file pointer and EOF is an integer. That's not how you check for EOF.

Comment: @adripanico That's perfectly fine in C. Welcome to the year 1999.

Comment: change `if(i > array_limit)` to `if(i >= array_limit)`

Comment: values has elements 0 to 99 so will crash with index 100

Comment: @Lundin That's perfectly fine with the compiler. The C specification have never allowed it.

Comment: @adripanico C99 allows it not C89

Comment: @adripanico The C standard was changed to allow it in 1999. Your C knowledge is 15 years outdated.

Comment: @Lunding I'll have to trust you because I am not able to find anything that says otherwise :)

Comment: @adripanico Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99. "intermingled declarations and code: variable declaration is no longer restricted to file scope or the start of a compound statement (block), similar to C++"

Comment: Guys even just this throws a fault... wtf am I not seeing

 #include <stdio.h>


int main (void)

{  

FILE *ifp;
ifp = fopen("samplepopulation.txt", "r");  
fclose(ifp);
   
   
    
return 0;
    
}

Comment: actually, all of those declarations are at the beginning of blocks. this is even legal in c89

Comment: @user3475432: Calling `fclose()` on an illegal pointer is undefined behaviour, and you didn't check if `fopen()` succeeded, so I would guess it failed...

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while (ifp!= EOF);
```

to

```
while (!feof(ifp));
```

Also scan from file like this:

```
if (fscanf(ifp, "%f", &sample)==EOF) //EOF if input failure
   break;
```

Comment: And in addition, check the result from fscanf and see if it is EOF. The code seems to have confused when to use feof() and when to check for EOF.

Comment: What if read fails with ferror? In that case feof will never be true and hence it'll be infinite loop.

Comment: "The fscanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure."

Comment: `while(!feof(ifp))` is just plain wrong, [this has been explained over, and over, and over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem But here the read error is being taken care of. So this works fine.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: `EOF` isn't an error, `ferror` isn't dealt with at all. If there really was a read-error, then checking for `feof` will get you nowhere. Besides, I think the issue here could well be `fclose(possible_null_ptr);`

Answer (score 0):

You might like to change this

```
fclose(ifp);
```

to become

```
if (NULL != ifp)
{
  fclose(ifp);
}
```

or simply move into the else branch:

```
    ...

    fclose(ifp)
  }

  return 0;
}
```